# Use AWK to split substring by last n characters in to a new column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, csv-simple

I have a large `.csv` file where I need to split a specific column by string length. I'm trying to take the last 6 characters of column 2 and move them into a new column.

**Current**:

```
3102017,90131112,0,740
3022017,8903944,90,0
3092017,127037191,475,0
```

**Desired**:

```
3102017,90,131112,0,740
3022017,8,903944,90,0
3092017,127,037191,475,0
```

Comment: What to do to rows with six or less digits in the second column?

Comment: Your title says "use awk" but you also tagged perl; please be clear as to whether you need a tool-specific solution or are open to any (or some)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a POSIX-compliant `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/.{6}$/, OFS "&", $2); print}'
```

With a POSIX-compliant `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\)\([^,]\{6\}\)/\1,\2/'
```

Those modify the lines only if the second field is at least 6 characters long (note that it will happily change `111,123456,333` to `111,,123456,333` leaving the second field empty).

Comment: Much easier: `sed 's/.\{6\},/,&/2'`

Comment: @Philippos However, your solution breaks if the first field is shorter than 6 characters.  Which is a shame, really, :)

Comment: Nitpicking duel? (-; The behaviour in this case is undefined. Solution above adds an empty second field for six digits, but not for five. Maybe better `sed 's/[^,]\{,6\},/,&/2'`, which always adds a second field and is still shorter. (-:

Comment: maybe `'{sub(/.{6}$/, OFS"&", $2); print}'` instead of `'{gsub(/.{6}$/, ",&", $2); print}'`?

Comment: @iruvar, good points. Changed.

Answer (score 3):

KISS approach, with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{l=length($2); if (l>6) {$2=substr($2,1,l-6) OFS substr($2,l-5)}} 1' OFS=, file
3102017,90,131112,0,740
3022017,8,903944,90,0
3092017,127,037191,475,0
```

Comment: I like this answer as it will always give an extra column, even if the string in column 2 is too small.

Answer (score 2):

With a `sed` implementation with support for extended regular expressions, assumes at least 6 characters in 2nd column for all lines

```
$ sed -E 's/,([^,]*)([^,]{6}),/,\1,\2,/' ip.csv 
3102017,90,131112,0,740
3022017,8,903944,90,0
3092017,127,037191,475,0
```

- `-E` for extended regular expressions, some implementations need `-r` instead
- `,([^,]*)([^,]{6}),` will match `,` 2nd column and `,`

  - 2nd column is captured in two groups with last 6 characters in 2nd group
- `,\1,\2,` replace as desired

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`, since `sed` and `awk` are already taken:

```
perl -F, -lpe 'splice @F, 1, 1, ($F[1] =~ m/^(\d+)(\d{6})$/g); $_ = join ",", @F' file
```

With `vim`, just for fun:

```
:%s/\m,\d*\zs\ze\d\{6},/,/
```

Comment: can you explain the use of splice here? `perl -F, -lane '$F[1]=~s/.{6}$/,$&/; print join ",", @F'` would be similar to awk solution..

Comment: @Sundeep No real reason, I suppose I was thinking in terms of arrays.

Comment: oh okay.. I did get to check the doc what is splice ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/(,.*?,)/$1 =~ s!......,!,$&!r /e'  x.csv
```

- substitute second field (`,.*?,`) by the ...
- result of the substitution ( `=~ s! ...!...!r`) of last 6 digits (`......`) by them and and a `,`